# Status Bar Color Turn Black Even if color set to white its change when swipe up but change again when we left swipe

Tags: swift, navigation

Status Bar Color Turn Black Even if color set to white its change when swipe up but change again when we left swipe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgW1r.png)

Comment: How you change statusbar color?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use it

```
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
           let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first 
           let statusBar = UIView(frame: window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame ?? CGRect.zero)
           statusBar.backgroundColor = .white
           window?.addSubview(statusBar)
    } else {
           UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = .white
           UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
    }
```